# Change intellisense autocomplete for Try

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, autocomplete, try-catch, intellisense

When you type try and hit enter, it automatically types out

```
  Try

    Catch excError As Exception

        WriteLog(excError)

    End Try
```

This is not a snippet, I've looked. The snippet version has ApplicationException instead of Exception. Does anyone know where this is stored so I can change it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a snippet because that is not the standard auto-complete for `Try` either

Answer (score 1):

You did not identify what version of Visual Studio, however here is how to modify the default Try/catch code snippets in Visual Studio Community 2015:

Tools -> Code Snippets Manager -> Language [Choose desired language in drop down] -> Code Patterns -> Error Handling

Highlight the desired code snippet and take note of the value in the location textbox above the split panel. Close Visual Studio as the .snippet file is most likely in use with Visual Studio open. Navigate to the path listed in the location text box and open the .snippet file with your favorite text editor. The .snippet file is a xml file; the actual code that is inserted by Intellisense is contained in the `<Code><!CDATA[[]]></Code>` node at the end of the file. Modify the code in within the `CDATA` block to what you wish Intellisense to insert for that code snippet and save the file.

Here is what the default `<Code><!CDATA[[]]></Code>` node should look like in the default Visual Basic Try/Catch snippet:

```
<Code Language="VB" Kind="method body"><![CDATA[Try

Catch ex As $ExceptionType$

End Try]]></Code>
```